# Not able to multiply the output of the code below

Tags: matrix, algebraic-manipulation, factorization

It is the output of the code given below

```
a1od = SuperDagger[a1o]; 
a1id = SuperDagger[a1i]; 

b1id = SuperDagger[b1i]; 
b1od = SuperDagger[b1o]; 
a2id = SuperDagger[a2i]; 

a2od = SuperDagger[a2o]; 
b2id = SuperDagger[b2i]; 
b2od = SuperDagger[b2o]; 
a3id = SuperDagger[a3i]; 
a3od = SuperDagger[a3o]; 
Unprotect[Conjugate];
Conjugate /: MakeBoxes[Conjugate[x_], StandardForm] := TemplateBox[{Parenthesize[x, StandardForm, Power]}, "Conjugate", DisplayFunction -> (SuperscriptBox[#1, "*"] & )]
Protect[Conjugate]; 



 f = Array[Subscript[U, FromDigits[{##1}]] & , {10, 10}] . (Array[Subscript[np, FromDigits[{##1}]] & , {10}] /. {Subscript[np, 1] -> a1od, Subscript[np, 2] -> b1od, 
  Subscript[np, 3] -> a2od, Subscript[np, 4] -> b2od, Subscript[np, 5] -> a3od, Subscript[np, 6] -> a1o, Subscript[np, 7] -> b1o, Subscript[np, 8] -> a2o, 
  Subscript[np, 9] -> b2o, Subscript[np, 10] -> a3o}); 

MatrixForm[Outer[Times, f, Conjugate[f] /. {a1o -> a1od, b1o -> b1od, a2o -> a2od, b2od -> b2o, a3od -> a3o, a1od -> a1o, b1od -> b1o, a2od -> a2o, b2od -> b2o, a3od -> a3o}][[1,1]]]
```

The output of the code looks something like this (used as a representation)
[image]
I am not able to get mixed terms of these two brackets.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this does what you want:

```
result = Outer[Times, f, 
   Conjugate[f] /. {a1o -> a1od, b1o -> b1od, a2o -> a2od, 
     b2od -> b2o, a3od -> a3o, a1od -> a1o, b1od -> b1o, a2od -> a2o, 
     b2od -> b2o, a3od -> a3o}];
result[[1, 1]] /. {
    x : Conjugate[Plus[y__]] :> Distribute[x, Plus, Conjugate]
    } /. {
   x : Conjugate[Plus[y__]] :> Distribute[x, Times, Conjugate]
   } // Expand
```

Comment: Thanks. I used //FunctionExpand and Expand[] and it worked strangely enough.